# Azure VNET Subnet delegation

Tags: azure, vnet

Can someone help explain Subnet delegation in Azure?

I've read the following article which don't really explain anything:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/subnet-delegation-overview

What is the purpose? When would I need it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Subnet Delegation is commonly used to allow a PaaS service  to be injected into an existing virtual network. An example of this would be the **Azure Databricks** service.

If you deploy DataBricks without VNet injection (the default option), a new dedicated VNet will be created for the DataBricks instance. The worker nodes of the cluster, which are Azure VMs, will be connected the new VNet.

If you don't want to create a new dedicated VNet, but instead use an existing VNet, you can deploy DataBricks with VNet injection. You basically grant the DataBricks service to control certain aspects of a subnet, within an existing VNet. This process is referred to as Subnet Delegation. It allows a PaaS service to make certain configuration changes, like adding Network Security Group rules (if a subnet is attached to an NSG), or configure custom routes.

You can only delegate a subnet to a single resource type. That's why you often create dedicated subnets for Azure PaaS services.

[image: Azure Portal showing subnet delegation for Azure DataBricks]

The screenshot above shows that two subnets are delegated to the Microsoft.DataBricks/workspaces.

Comment: that makes sense. What if i wan't both Databricks and a Web App in the same subnet? is that possible? or can a subnet only be delegated to a single Azure service?
I'm worried then that we should group our application into seperate VNET's instead of seperate subnets if each Application is going to need multiple subnets for different delegations of various services. Web apps in one subnet, storage in another, messaging in a third, etc.

Comment: You can only delegate a subnet to a single resource type. Otherwise, two services would theoretically apply conflicting configurations to a subnet. It's common to use dedicated subnets for PaaS services. Some Azure services, check during deployment if subnets are not already used by other services. If this is detected, deployments fail.

Comment: Be aware that subnet delegation is not always applicable if you want to connect an Azure PaaS service to a VNet. Some services support [Private Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-link-overview#:~:text=%20Azure%20Private%20Link%20provides%20the%20following%20benefits:,endpoint%20is%20mapped%20to%20an%20instance...%20More), which creates a private endpoint in your VNet. Traffic can flow over the VNet instead of the public Internet. App Services and storage support private link.